# How Can I Create "Sub-Dashboards" in Looker?

Tags: dashboard, looker

Good morning, all you fine folks in Codelandia. I had a question for anyone out there who has experience using Looker, as I am very new to using this particular software.

I have been tasked to migrate multiple dashboards and visualizations to from our old interface to Looker, and I would like to add more organization to the new setup. The idea I have is to create one "master" dashboard with several sub-dashboards housed within in the master.

The idea would be something like this:

[image: Layout of Tabs]

Is it possible that one of you knows if this is possible and/or how to do it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize HTML in text boxes to create tabs on your dashboard (in essence links to a completely different dashboard). Here is an example: https://community.looker.com/dashboards-looks-7/tabbed-dashboard-14990

This might be as close as you're going to get.